# Should we combine these questions?

Tags: discussion

This new user has been walking forward with homework questions, and the irritating part is that he has not learned from previously asked questions, instead keeps looking for the answers.

So his approach involves setting a topic: nodal analysis, then enumerating it for a particular case. or more importantly, the question seems more about how to mathematically describe the current for nodal analysis.

[Solve a circuit with the nodal analysis (2)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/216784/solve-a-circuit-with-the-nodal-analysis-2)

[Solve a circuit with the nodal analysis (1)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/211511/solve-a-circuit-with-the-nodal-analysis-1)

[How to find the current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/216647/how-to-find-the-current)

<strike>[Solve a circuit with the nodal analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/216848/solve-a-circuit-with-the-nodal-analysis)</strike>

I don't that's ideal for this forum, nor would anyone who's curious to learn about a topic (KCL in this csae) should have to browse through multiple questions to gain full understanding of **how to mathematically describe a current flowing through a branch**.

Should these questions be combined to a single question, and the answer contain multiple cases?

Comment: I am thinking more along the lines of obliterating from orbit...

Comment: Isn't there some way we could limit users with experience of under 5 or 10 experience to cajole them into asking better questions. There almost needs to be a homework disclaimer button and warning when people ask questions. This is just a wild idea, I hope people will come up with some of their own. Here is another idea: maybe there could be a popup that is timed to prevent closure for people with low experience (new users) that would force them to at least read the rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not too sure what exactly you want. Perhaps these two questions ([1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/211511/solve-a-circuit-with-the-nodal-analysis-1)) ([2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/216848/solve-a-circuit-with-the-nodal-analysis)) are similar enough to merge, but the others aren't.

Homework questions are explicitly allowed. You can't get upset for someone asking about a homework problem - save that for the people who just post a picture of a homework problem and expect results.

I've looked through the questions, and they generally follow all the guidelines we like to see in homework questions:

- There is a clear schematic
- Effort is demonstrated towards solving the question
- The question is more about how to solve the question than begging for an answer
- The writing is clear and the equations are formatted nicely

Honestly, I don't see issues with the questions as they stand. If you say "they didn't learn" then I will hand it right back to you with "you didn't teach". I'm glad to hear that you didn't have any issues learning material with any of your studies, but not everyone learns that way.